# Is there a way to send variable from node.js without re-rendering?

Tags: node.js, ejs

i want to change property `name` inside index.ejs file without rerender.
is it possible ?

*app.js*

```
app.get('/about', function(req,res){
    res.render('index',{name: 'test'});
});
```

index.ejs

```
.
.
.
<h2><%- name %></h2>
.
.
.
```

Comment: I think you can't without adding some AJAX script if the changes are server-side

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your answer. I am going to use ReactJs. Thats the better way i hope.